# Plotly graph shows a blank space on GitHub

Tags: python-3.x, github, ipython, plotly, github-pages

I am using Plotly to make graphs in my IPython notebook. I am able to view graphs on my IPython notebook when I upload them on GitHub they are displayed as blank spaces.

I read on the web that Plotly currently does not support iframes and hence the issue, but is there a workaround?

Here's the link to my GitHub Ipython notebook:

```
https://github.com/dhavalbhinde/bhinde_dhaval_spring2017/blob/master/Finals/Analysis%203.ipynb
```

Please, can someone advice how should I handle them?

Comment: see: https://community.plot.ly/t/plots-are-not-showing-on-github/241

Answer (score 8):

I found a way to show Plotly plots on Github. They aren’t interactive anymore but it’s better than nothing.

First

```
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers
```

you can see the list of available renders.

*if you get an error on this step you can simply just install orca:

```
conda install -c plotly plotly-orca
```

and then there are 2 possible ways.
you can pass "svg" to `.show()` like this:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(iris, x=transformed_iris['component1'], y=transformed_iris['component2'], z=transformed_iris['component3'],color='species')

fig.show(renderer="svg")
```

or you can set the pio.renderers.default to svg:

```
pio.renderers.default = "svg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Import these and this and it will work :

```
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't work... Any more hitns?